# Rest API returning byte[] i response

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

What should be in the consumes and produces for Rest API which is returning byte[] of file in the response.
No file params are included in the request .

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below for returning byte[]

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'MultipartFile' for the purpose of consuming and sending back a file in response.

You can have a look at the following tutorial at spring.io for detailed tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the media type on basis of file content type.

for example:

```
  @GetMapping
  public HttpEntity returnByteArray() {
      String filepath = ; //filepath
      String contentType = FileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap().getContentType(filePath);
      byte[] byteContent = ; //Content
      final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(contentType));
      return new HttpEntity(byteContent, headers);
}
```

**OR**

If you always return the same content file type then you can also set in

```
    @GetMapping(produces = "mime_type")
    public byte[] returnByteArray() {
      return new byte[0];
    }
```